# Retrofit logging interceptor exception

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to enable Logging with Retrofit but I am getting this exception:

```
07-13 12:44:53.278 28698-29248/com.xxxx.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                                                                                         Process: com.xxxx.debug, PID: 28698
                                                                                         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method log(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Platform; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Platform' appears in /data/data/com.xxxx.debug/files/instant-run/dex/slice-realm-optional-api_16b022358933b490d810e358ea76b13cd4d88163-classes.dex)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:157)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:190)
                                                                                             at com.xxxx.api.RetrofitClient$1.intercept(RetrofitClient.java:59)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:190)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
                                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And this is how I am doing it:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static MyService instance;

    public static MyService getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = newInstance(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static MyService newInstance(Context context) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(context.getString(R.string.base_url))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getClient())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(MyService.class);
    }

    @NonNull
    private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();

                        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("api-key", "...")
                                .header("version-app", "-")
                                .header("platform", "android")
                                .header("version", "-")
                                .header("device", "-")
                                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                .build();

                        Response response = chain.proceed(request);// <-- CRASH

                        return response;
                    }
                })
                .addInterceptor(interceptor);

        return httpClient.build();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding only one interceptor but still crashing. I am using this dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** Well this is embarrassing... the problem solved itself. I changed nothing, I am revising all my commits and both `RetrofitClient` and `build.gradle` haven't changed. The problem, therefore, was not related to gradle dependencies or versions.

Luckily someone will cast some light on this exception!

Answer (score 38):

Retrofit 2.1.0 relies on OkHttp 3.3.0, so I would use the same version for the Logging Interceptor (which is part of OkHttp):

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

Can you try to add the below dependency

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

And let me know if there is any progress

You can also refer this [link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5131).

Answer (score 1):

In my case this pair of dependencies solved the problem:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

Anyway, the problem is in dependency consistency...

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, if you facing this issue sometime not randomly then try to restart android studio with Invalidate/Restart. Maybe its fixed in future updates.

**1. Uninstall previous build.

 2. File-> Invalidate/Cache -> Invalidate and
        restart.**

Comment: Rajesh, how can this theoretically help to solve the problem? Can you explain?